# Google Sheets query, unable to decipher error message

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to copy data over from one sheet to another using Google Sheets and am using this query in the second sheet

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("5UAxxxxxxxxxxxx-GMcxccccccccp-xsdff0","SheetName!A4:AI1000"),"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col7, Col9, Col14, Col16, Col 18, Col19, Col20, Col21 where Col35 = 'Yes'")
```

Unable to understand what this error means.

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <INTEGER_LITERAL> "18 "" at line 1, column 62. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...
```

My Sheet1 where I am copying data from has columns A-Z and AA-AI, so I have A4:AI1000 to capture all the data assuming we won't have more than 1000 records with the headers taking up from 1-3 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple one, you have a space between in the column reference `Col 18`.

The error message was pretty clear:

- `QUERY Parameter 2` is the query string itself
- `Encountered " <INTEGER_LITERAL> "18 ""` means that it found the number 18 when it was expecting either a column reference or an SQL clause…

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if this was data related or query related but this solved the issue.